# Procedure for assay of chemicals X and Y - or - Procedure for assaying chemicals X and Y

Tags: phrase-choice

A sentence from a document describing the contents of a pharmaceutical tablet and the prodecure helping to determine whether a tablet has the proper content:

> The procedure **for assaying** ethinyl estradiol and chlormadinone is described in the Assay section.
>
> The procedure **for assay of** ethinyl estradiol and chlormadinone is described in the Assay section.

Which of the two looks more natural? I've found the "for assay of" combination while googling on the topic.

Comment: [Assay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assay) is a verb, especially in chemistry, so I believe the first one is correct.

Comment: For the second one, I suppose it should be "for *the* assay of". For actual usage this might be a good question for Chemistry SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.  However since "assay" can be used as both verb (to perform the assay) and noun (the output of the assay) I find the second one more natural. (I am native Australian English speaker, but not a chemist or geologist etc)